# Pros & cons between <MyComp /> and React.createElement(MyComp)

Tags: reactjs

What's main idea to use  React.createElement ?

What's differences between :

```
const myProps = { initialValue: 1 };
const Comp = React.createElement(MyComp, { ...myProps, ref: "mycomp" });
```

And

```
<MyComp ref="mycomp"    initialValue ="1"   />
```

Comment: As per [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) **JSX just provides syntactic sugar for the React.createElement(component, props, ...children) function.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<MyComp ref="mycomp" initialValue ="1"   />`

transpiles to:

```
"use strict";

React.createElement(MyComp, { ref: "mycomp", initialValue: "1" });
```

Which is not too different from

```
const myProps = { initialValue: 1 };
const Comp = React.createElement(MyComp, { ...myProps, ref: "mycomp" });
```

---

The main differences in terms of usages are quite subjective; some people find it the JSX declarative syntax easier to understand but this is beyond the scope of SO.